# Graphicsmagick: combing multiple images are splitting to next line after 1536px

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

Using GraphicsMagick I have tried something like this

```
gm montage -geometry 256x256 6-0-0.jpg 6-1-0.jpg 6-2-0.jpg 6-3-0.jpg 6-4-0.jpg 6-5-0.jpg 6-6-0.jpg 6-7-0.jpg final.jpg
```

Its creating final.jpg of size `1536x512` instead of `2048x256`.
How can I fix the issue to create a horizontal image of height 256px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the parameter -tile 8x1 (see https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#tile)

```
$ gm montage -geometry 256x256 -tile 8x1 6-0-0.png 6-1-0.png 6-2-0.png 6-3-0.png 6-4-0.png 6-5-0.png 6-6-0.png 6-7-0.png final.png
$ identify final8.png 
final8.png PNG 2048x256 2048x256+0+0 16-bit sRGB 361KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```